# ionic tab view gone when clicking on a tab

Tags: angular, tabs, ionic4

I searched for the solution, but didn't find any match in this case.

I have created a page called "entertainment" and inside that I have created two other pages called "monthly" and "special" *inside the entertainment folder.*
FYI , the folder structure is look alike this.

- entrtainment

  - monthly
  - special

The entertainment page's route look like as follows.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EntertainmentPage
  },
  {
    path: 'monthly',
    loadChildren: () => import('./monthly/monthly.module').then( m => m.MonthlyPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'special',
    loadChildren: () => import('./special/special.module').then( m => m.SpecialPageModule)
  }
];
```

Also the tab view looks like as follow.

```
  <ion-tabs >
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" style="width: 100% !important;">
      <ion-tab-button tab = 'monthly'>
        <ion-icon name="fast-food"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Food</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab = 'special'>
        <ion-icon name="beer"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Alcohol</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
```

**But when I clicked on a given tab the page is loaded and the undelying tab is gone**. Any suggestion on this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you have added `router-outlet` for the same?

Comment: no, I didn't add any router outlet. Would you please elaborate more

Comment: The routes monthly and special are wrong, they should be added as children of entertainmentPage so that the tabs keep apeearing on its childern, while in this current way you are doing, monthly and special are being opened as new separate page from entertainment page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of [@Mostafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12125320/mostafa-harb)

So what I just missed is, add each and every tab route as child route.

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: EntertainmentPage,
    children:[
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'monthly',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'monthly',
        loadChildren: () => import('./monthly/monthly.module').then( m => m.MonthlyPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'special',
        loadChildren: () => import('./special/special.module').then( m => m.SpecialPageModule)
      },
    ]
  }
```